# How to find posts which the user hasn't viewed using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a database of objects like these bellow:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="../public", static_url_path="")

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)


class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False, unique=True)
    post_viewed = relationship(
        "PostViewed", back_populates="author", cascade="all, delete-orphan"
    )

class PostViewed(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "post_viewed"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable=True)
    author = relationship("User", back_populates="post_viewed")
    post_id = db.Column(db.String, db.ForeignKey("posts.id"), nullable=False)
    post = relationship("Post", back_populates="post_viewed")


class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "posts"
    id = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(124), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    post_viewed = relationship("PostViewed", back_populates="post", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
```

I need a way to sort posts by post_viewed table, using SQLAlchemy. So I can show the user posts, they haven't viewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show only not viewed posts by `User(id=user_id)` you can use `subquery`:

```py
seen_posts = session.query(
    Post.id.label('post_id')
).join(
    PostViewed
).filter(
    PostViewed.author_id = user_id
).subquery()
not_seen_posts = Post.query.filter(~Post.id.in_(seen_posts))
```

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work. Could there be a way to find out the posts the user has viewed and return posts that are not in the users_post_viewed?

Comment: @DorcyShema my mistake. You are right. That solution showed not-seen posts for user_id but only from set of posts seen by other users. Now, I fixed the solution and should work as desired.

Comment: This works great, however, I am receiving a warning that says: `SAWarning: Coercing Subquery object into a select() for use in IN(); please pass a select() construct explicitly` on this line `not_seen_posts = Post.query.filter(~Post.id.in_(seen_posts))`